# Mysql find records if specific key exists

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql which name track_questions, table have a following fields:

```
id: AUTO_INCREMENT
question_id: Foreign key question table
status: enum('entered','checked','verified','dissipated')
date: date
```

Unique: question_id and status combination

When question insert in database the question_id with status "entered" inserted in track table. When QA check that question the second status inserted with status of "checked" and so on.

I have some record in table which not have "entered" status, and my start tracking point those question which have entered status. After deploy code some question are in admin and other pool so some other status entered without entry of starting point. I want to remove all question id which not have entered status. And if question_id has entered status then other status remain as it is.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and show the result of the desired operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to remove all question id which not have `entered` status.

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM track_questions t1
LEFT JOIN track_questions t2 ON t1.question_id = t2.question_id
                            AND t2.status = 'entered'
WHERE t2.question_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Your answer is working fine Akina
Unable to upvote you, because I am new user.